# Calling a contract from a called contract

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, contract-debugging

I'm trying to make nested calls or whatever they are called. I always get **out of gas** exception. What am I missing?

From JS side I do `caller.makeCall(firstAddress, secondAddress, {gas:300000, value: 300000000000000000}, callback)`

Here are the contracts:

```
contract caller {
    function makeCall(address first, address second){
        first.call.gas(100000).value(200000000000000000)(bytes4(bytes32(sha3('makeCall(address)'))), second);
    }
}

contract first {
    function makeCall(address second) {
        second.call.gas(100000).value(100000000000000000)(bytes4(bytes32(sha3('make()'))));
    }
}

contract second {
    uint public x = 1;
    function make(){
        x = 2;
    }
    function(){
        x = 3;
    }
}
```

I've double checked everything. I've supplied  up to 3 million gas and still get **out of gas** exception.

Here's a tx https://testnet.etherscan.io/tx/0xf5986e85f7601e6a896eda22d72cb302d59013f9750c9997bf112acea757f839

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whew, I've found a bug.

So, the problem was that `first.call.gas(100000)` forwards to contract `first` exactly this amount. When EVM control reaches `second.call.gas(100000)` it forwards this amount to contract **second** and as a result there's no more gas left for contract **first**. And that's where **out of gas** exception comes from.
Now, I've changed `first.call.gas(100000)` to `first.call.gas(200000)` and everything works just fine.

- caller has 0.1 ether balance
- first has 0.1 ether balance
- second has 0.1 ether balance
- uint public x == 2

Answer (score 1):

You are changing the function parameters not the gas values. See the [documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/control-structures.html?highlight=extends#external-function-calls) for the correct syntax of calling external contract methods from contracts.

Never use **call()** for methods that change the state of the block chain. **call()** is used only to query (read) the block chain.